# ChromeOptions AddUserProfilePreference

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am using Webdriver 3.3.1 with Java. I am trying to disable the pop-up asking to save passwords. Based on search results I need to use
ChromOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("","")
However, there is no AddUserProfilePreference 
the only add method is addArguments.

I am using Eclipse Neon.2 and Java 1.8

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With ChromeDriver 2.28 & Selenium 3.3.1, the following works:

```
final DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
final ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
Map<String, Object> prefs = new LinkedHashMap<>();
prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", Boolean.valueOf(false));
prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", Boolean.valueOf(false));
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: finally had a chance to put this in place. Works perfectly.
THANKS!

Comment: ChromeDriver(capabilities) is deprecated
Not sure what the alternative method is.

Comment: It seems now, the correct method is to create a ChromeOptions object and do options.merge(capabilities) then pass options to ChromeDriver constructor.

Answer (score 4):

Add the below chrome options:

```
Map<String, Object> prefs =new HashMap<String, Object>();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("disable-extensions");
prefs .put("credentials_enable_service", false);
prefs .put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: Hi, Where can I get the complete list of values that I can use with prefs.put.  Thanks

Comment: I don't have the complete list but you can do many things using prefs.put. Some of them are : 
1. Set a Chrome preference 
 **prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);**    
2. Set Binary   
 **prefs.put("binary", "/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser");**
3. Download directory path   
 **prefs.put("download.default_directory", refPath);**
4. two are already given in the solution.
 Thanks!