# Disabling save password prompts in Chrome when running gui tests

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, webdriver-io

When running acceptance tests in Chrome, where part of the flow is logging in, Chrome prompts you to save the password (thus obscuring part of the window with this prompt). How can I configure WebDriverIO so that it tells Chrome not to show the prompt?

From [several](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/26275/how-to-disable-chrome-save-your-password-selenium-java) [google](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44145437/200987) [searches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43102592/200987), I have learned that the right setting for the ChromeDriver is called `credentials_enable_service`, but it is always set using the Ruby, Java or Python api for Selenium, and I don't know how or where to set it in the static WebDriver config object.

It seems obvious that it should be under `capabilities.chromeOptions`, but directly placing it there spits out an error from wdio about an unknown option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I [found an example where the setting was applied](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4145#issuecomment-285801694) to the Protracter framework, and it turns out the configuration could be copied verbatim to WebDriverIO.

There is a `prefs` property under `capabilities.chromeOptions` that can be used to set profile preferences in Chrome. This is all that is required:

```
capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'chromeOptions': {
      'prefs': {
          'credentials_enable_service': false,
```

Comment: If someone can find any proper documentation of this, feel free to edit this post and add links to the documentation.